# Memory issue when read excel file with Apache poi

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, apache-poi

i have memory problems when i try to read a excel file (5.9Mb, 37 columns in total, and 7 columns with formula like SUM(A1:A50))  using apache poi library (version 3.16). Here is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<ReturnObject> readExcel(InputStream inputStreamExcelData) {

    ArrayList<ReturnObject> list = new ArrayList<ReturnObject>();

    try {
        //Here is the problem
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStreamExcelData);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();

            ReturnObject reg = new ReturnObject();

            Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(0);
            reg.setData1(getValueCell(cell));

            cell = nextRow.getCell(1);
            reg.setData2(getValueCell(cell));

            list.add(reg);
        }

        workbook.close();
        inputStreamExcelData.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }
    return list;
}
```

The getValueCell function:

```
  public static String getValueCell(Cell cell) {

    String result = "";

    if (cell != null) {

        switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
        case STRING:
            result = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;
        case NUMERIC:
            Double num = cell.getNumericCellValue();
            result = num.longValue() + "";
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {

                String value = sdf.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
                return value;
            }
            break;
        case FORMULA:
            CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
            result = cellValue.getStringValue();
        default:
            break;
        }
     }

     return result;
 }
```

Main method

```
public static void main(String... args){
      InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/files/file.xlsm");
      List<ReturnObjec>  r = readExcel(is);
      System.out.ptintln(r);
}
```

The class ReturnObjec:

```
 public class ReturnObject{
    private String data1;
    private String data2;
    ... setters and getters ...

}
```

When i run for first time, it works correctly, but my memory usage increase considerably (58% to 74%) and stay here. When i run a secont attemp the memory usage increase one more time to 77% and then, i get a memory leak exception.

> Exception in thread "ajp-bio-8009-AsyncTimeout" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>       at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.iterator(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:663)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:157)

How can i manage this memory problem? I thought that *workbook.close()* would free some memory, but it doesn't  happens.

Comment: How big is `list`?  What happens when `list`is returned?  Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, along with what the Excel needs to contain.

Comment: I updated my question frind Andrex. List is litle, it only has 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **XSSF and SAX (Event API)**. Reading should look something like this:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(filename);
XSSFReader r = new XSSFReader( pkg );
```

More information visit [XSSF SAX API](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) and [SXSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html#SXSSF+%28Since+POI+3.8+beta3%29).

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, i used XLSX2CSV class  (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java) and resolved my problem. Thanks!!